# How to avoid permission issues on a secondary drive after reinstalling Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-8, file-management

Every time I reinstall Windows on my main drive, everything on other drives breaks due to permissions.

I'm unable to do most things on the other drives due to them being 'owned' by the previous user id from the older Windows installation.

I know you can fix the issue by re-taking ownership of the files and fixing the ACL, but I'd like to avoid the issue altogether.

Is there some setting I can use that 'voids' all user permissions on secondary drives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no real "easy" way to avoid this problem. Every file system needs some kind of access control. If you want to avoid this you may backup you file system with some backup tool and restore it after you reinstalled your system.